# How to deal with JSON and variant objects?

Tags: c#, .net, json, javascriptserializer

I'm using .NET's `JavascriptSerializer` to deserialize JSON into runtime objects and for the most part the mapping between JSON fields and object fields has been automatic. However, I am faced with the following scenario and would welcome advice on how to handle it.

Imagine we have a JSON representation of a Shape, which can be a Square or a Circle. For example,

```
{"ShapeType":"Circle","Shape":{"Color":"Blue", "Radius":"5.3"}}
```

or

```
{"ShapeType":"Square","Shape":{"Color":"Red", "Side":"2.1"}}
```

These JSON strings are modeled after the class hierarchy shown below.

```
class ShapePacket
{
    public string ShapeType;  // either "Square" or "Circle"
    public Shape Shape;
}

class Shape   // all Shapes have a Color
{
    public string Color;
}

class Square : Shape
{
    public float Side;
}

class Circle : Shape
{
    public float Radius;
}
```

Simply calling `JavascriptSerializer.Deserialize` doesn't work in this case, where there is a variant type involved. Is there any way to coax `JavascriptSerializer` to deserialize despite the "branch" in my data type? I am also open to third-party solutions.

Comment: Looks similar to this question [JSON serialization of array with polymorphic objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186973/json-serialization-of-array-with-polymorphic-objects).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The branch in your data type likely necessitates a branch in your code. I don't believe there's a way to do this besides the explicit way.

**I would do this in two steps:**

First, turn the incoming JSON object into a typeless hash using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`

Then, manually branch on the 'ShapeType' field to choose the appropriate `Shape` class (`Square` or `Circle`), and construct an instance yourself.

*(explicit solution included here for posterity, although I suspect you don't need my help with it ;)*

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to initialize the JavascriptSerializer with a JavaScriptTypeResolver implementation like this (SimpleTypeResolver is built-in in the class library):

```
new JavaScriptSerializer(new SimpleTypeResolver());
```

in order to enable automatic type resolution. I think as a result it will add a __type field to the output JSON, which it will later use to resolve back the type.