# JSON Deserialization with an array of polymorphic objects

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-3, json.net

I'm having a problem with JSON Deserialization involving an array of polymorphic objects. I've tried the solutions for serialization documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186973/json-serialization-of-array-with-polymorphic-objects) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254872/using-json-net-converters-to-deserialize-properties) which work great for serialization, but both blow up on deserialization.

My class structure is as follows:

IDable

```
[DataContract(IsReference=true)]
public abstract class IDable<T> {

    [DataMember]
    public T ID { get; set; }
}
```

Observation Group

```
[DataContract(IsReference=true)]
[KnownType(typeof(DescriptiveObservation))]
[KnownType(typeof(NoteObservation))]
[KnownType(typeof(NumericObservation))]
[KnownType(typeof(ScoredObservation))]
public class ObservationGroup : IDable<int> {

    [DataMember]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<Observation> Observations { get; set; }

    [OnDeserializing]
    void OnDeserializing(StreamingContext context)
    {
        init();
    }

    public ObservationGroup()  {
        init();
    }

    private void init()
    {
        Observations = new List<Observation>();
        ObservationRecords = new List<ObservationRecord>();
    }

}
```

DescriptiveObservation

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class DescriptiveObservation : Observation
{

    protected override ObservationType GetObservationType()
    {
        return ObservationType.Descriptive;
    }
}
```

NoteObservation

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class NoteObservation : Observation
{
    protected override ObservationType GetObservationType()
    {
        return ObservationType.Note;
    }
}
```

NumericObservation

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class NumericObservation : Observation
{
    [DataMember]
    public double ConstraintMaximum { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double ConstraintMinimum { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int PrecisionMaximum { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int PrecisionMinimum { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string UnitType { get; set; }

    protected override ObservationType GetObservationType()
    {
        return ObservationType.Numeric;
    }
}
```

ScoredObservation

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class ScoredObservation : Observation {
    [DataMember]
    public int Value { get; set; }

    protected override ObservationType GetObservationType() {
        return ObservationType.Scored;
    }
}
```

I'm impartial to using either the built in JavaScriptSerializer or the Newtonsoft JSON library.

Serialization Code

```
var settings = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.TypeNameHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.TypeNameHandling.Objects;

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(AnInitializedScoresheet, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, settings);
```

Deserialization Code

```
return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(returnedStringFromClient, typeof(Scoresheet));
//Scoresheet contains a list of observationgroups
```

The error that I get is

"Could not create an instance of type ProjectXCommon.DataStores.Observation. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantated."

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's related to your `List<Observation>` the deserializers are trying to instantiate a type of `Observation` not the specific type that it actually is. With Newtonsoft you can override parts of the deserialization by adding your own Converter (here is an example https://gist.github.com/1140171 ) I'm not sure how much this will help you though as I'm not entirely certain but fairly certain this is the case. :)

Comment: json samples would be helpful

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You have not added any settings upon deserialization. You need to apply settings with `TypeNameHandling` set to `Object` or `All`.

Like this:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(
    returnedStringFromClient, 
    typeof(Scoresheet), 
    new JsonSerializerSettings 
    { 
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects 
    });
```

Documentation: [**TypeNameHandling setting**](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm)

Comment: Doh! For those still using the .NET JavascriptSerializer you can also use  
`new JavaScriptSerializer(new System.Web.Script.Serialization.SimpleTypeResolver()).Deserialize(returnedStringFromClient, typeof(Scoresheet));`

Comment: As of RavenDB build 499 (RavenDB uses JSON.NET) when using a generic List where T is an interface, you need to add the [JsonProperty(TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All)] attribute. This fixes the exception "Could not create an instance of type 'your interface' Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantated."

Answer (score 2):

Use this [JsonKnownTypes](https://github.com/dmitry-bym/JsonKnownTypes), similar way to do that:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonKnownTypesConverter<BaseClass>))]
[JsonKnownType(typeof(Base), "base")]
[JsonKnownType(typeof(Derived), "derived")]
public class Base
{
    public string Name;
}
public class Derived : Base
{
    public string Something;
}
```

Now when you serialize object in json will be add `"$type"` with `"base"` and `"derived"` value and it will be use for deserialize

Serialized list example:

```
[
    {"Name":"some name", "$type":"base"},
    {"Name":"some name", "Something":"something", "$type":"derived"}
]
```