# How to deserialize collection with different types?

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I have a JSON feed that looks like this (I removed some fields that aren't necessary for this example):

```
{
  "total_count": 2,
  "num_pages": 1,
  "current_page": 1,
  "balance": {
    "amount": "0.00001199",
    "currency": "BTC"
  },
  "transactions": [
    {
      "transaction": {
        "id": "5018f833f8182b129c00002f",
        "created_at": "2012-08-01T02:34:43-07:00",
        "sender": {
          "id": "5011f33df8182b142400000e",
          "name": "User Two",
          "email": "user2@example.com"
        },
        "recipient": {
          "id": "5011f33df8182b142400000a",
          "name": "User One",
          "email": "user1@example.com"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "transaction": {
        "id": "5018f833f8182b129c00002e",
        "created_at": "2012-08-01T02:36:43-07:00",
        "hsh": "9d6a7d1112c3db9de5315b421a5153d71413f5f752aff75bf504b77df4e646a3",
        "sender": {
          "id": "5011f33df8182b142400000e",
          "name": "User Two",
          "email": "user2@example.com"
        },
        "recipient_address": "37muSN5ZrukVTvyVh3mT5Zc5ew9L9CBare"
      }
    }
 ]
}
```

There are two types of transactions in this feed: internal transactions that have a `recipient`, and external transactions that have a `hsh` and `recipient_address`.

I created the following classes to accomodate this structure:

[image: UML]

So we have a base class for all paged results (`PagedResult`) with a specific implementation for transactions (`TransactionPagedResult`). This result has a collection containing 0..* transactions (abstract class `Transaction`). They're not of the type `Transaction` though, but of type `InternalTransaction` or `ExternalTransaction` which are implementations of `Transaction`.

My question is how I can let JSON.NET handle this. I want JSON.NET to see whether the current transaction it's parsing is an `InternalTransaction` or an `ExternalTransaction`, and add the according type to the `IEnumerable<Transaction>` collection in `TransactionPagedResult`.

I created my own JsonConverter that I added as a property to the `IEnumerable<Transaction>` with the `[JsonConverter(typeof(TransactionCreationConverter))]` attribute, but this didn't work, I get the following error:

> Additional information: Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current
>   JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path 'transactions',
>   line 1, position 218.

I understand this is because JSON.NET tries to deserialize the whole collection, but I want it to deserialize each object inside the collection one by one.

Anyone?

Comment: good post so far, but could you please add the information of what exactly you mean by ... "but this didn't work" at the very end of your post?

Comment: Yes, I didn't add that because I didn't want the post to become too long. I get an error that the JsonReader item is not an object but an array (which is correct, since I placed the attribute on the IEnumerable collection). I want the JsonConverter to look at every single item in IEnumerable though, which are all objects.

Comment: @Jack I think you linked to the wrong thread?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699972/how-to-decode-a-json-string-using-c/7701070#7701070 edit: fixed link

Comment: @Jack no I don't really see how that would help. I understand how I can deserialize JSON to an object with JSON.NET, but my problem is that the feed can contain 2 different subtypes, and I want JSON.NET to deserialize them to the correct type.

Comment: This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7094955/json-deserialization-with-an-array-of-polymorphic-objects

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deserializing polymorphic json classes without type information using json.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19307752/deserializing-polymorphic-json-classes-without-type-information-using-json-net)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question is essentially a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19307752/10263), and the solution is the same.  You need a `JsonConverter` to instantiate the correct object.  However, there are a couple of differences that I see.

If you look at the converter implementation from the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19308474/10263), you can see that it looks for a boolean flag in the JSON to determine the type to instantiate.  In your case, there is not such a flag, so you'd need to use the existence or absence of a field to make this determination.  Also, your list of transactions in the JSON is actually a list of objects that *contain* transactions, so the converter needs to account for that as well.

With these changes, your converter should look something like this:

```
public class TransactionConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(Transaction).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, 
        Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken transaction = JToken.Load(reader)["transaction"];
        if (transaction["recipient"] != null)
        {
            return transaction.ToObject<InternalTransaction>();
        }
        else
        {
            return transaction.ToObject<ExternalTransaction>();
        }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, 
        object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

assuming that your classes are defined like this:

```
class TransactionPagedResult
{
    [JsonProperty(ItemConverterType=typeof(TransactionConverter))]
    public IEnumerable<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
}

class Transaction
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("created_at")]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}

class InternalTransaction : Transaction
{
    public User Recipient { get; set; }
}

class ExternalTransaction : Transaction
{
    public string Hsh { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("recipient_address")]
    public string RecipientAddress { get; set; }
}

class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Also, to answer the last part of your question, if you decorate your list with a `[JsonConverter]` attribute, the converter is expected to handle the entire list.  To handle the individual items, you need to use `[JsonProperty(ItemConverterType=typeof(TransactionConverter))]` on the list instead.  I've edited the class definitions above to make this clear.

Comment: Awesome! This does the trick :) Thanks a lot for the example and explanation! :)