# Deserialize JSON to known and unknown types in a class

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

I´m using C# MVC and have the following JSON:

```
MessageType: "Type1"

MessageData: {{Name: "Jonas"}, Phones: [{ Fixed: "12345", Mobile: "45678" }], Addresses: [{ Home: "ababa"} ... ], { HasId: "Yes }, ... }
```

The `MessageData` will contain different data depending on `MessageType`.

What I need is to deserialize it into the following C# structure:

```
public class AjaxMsg 
{
    public string MessageType { get; set; }
    public object MesssageData { get; set; }
}
```

I´m using the native serialization during the POST from client, but I only get the `MessageType` data.

Also, the code:

```
var msgDataString = MessageData.ToString()
```

returns `"System.Object"`

How can I get the `MessageData` accordingly as an object format ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19307752/deserializing-polymorphic-json-classes-without-type-information-using-json-net or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186973/json-serialization-of-array-with-polymorphic-objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a wrapper class to deserialize :

```
[Serializable]
public class AjaxMsg
{
    [DataMember]
    public string MessageType { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public object MessageData { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public IList< AjaxMsg> list {get;set;}
}

var obj = JsonConvert<Data>(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON.NET's `ToObject` method:

```
JObject Data = Message.MessageData; 
Type type = Message.MessageType;
object obj = Data.ToObject(type); // if you dont know the type in compile time

MyType obj2 = Data.ToObject<MyType>(); // if you know the type in compile time
```