# Serialize multiple objects of different types with JSON

Tags: c#, json, serialization, types

I have two classes which inherits from an abstract class

```
public class Class1 : MainBaseClass
{
   public int attrib1 {get; set;}
   public int attrib2 {get; set;}
}

public class Class2 : MainBaseClass
{
   public int attribx {get; set;}
   public int attriby {get; set;}
}
```

Then I created a list of type MainBaseClass in order to serialize both classes in one JSON string but I got this exception

> An exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Type 'MyProject.Class1' with data contract
>   name 'Class1:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyProject' is not
>   expected. Add any types not known statically to the list of known
>   types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by
>   adding them to the list of known types passed to
>   DataContractSerializer.

My method does this:

```
Class1 class1 = getData();
Class2 class2 = getData();
Package<MainBaseClass> package = new Package<MainBaseClass>();
package.AddObject(class1)
package.AddObject(class2);
//Here's the error
new ServiceClass().Serialize<Package<MainBaseClass>>(package);
```

My package class

```
public class Package<T>
{
    public List<T> Objects = new List<T>();

    public Package() { }

    public void AddObject(T dto)
    {
        this.Objects.Add(dto);
    }
}
```

My serializer method

```
    public static string Serialize<T>(T entity)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        //Here's the exception
        ser.WriteObject(stream, entity);
        stream.Position = 0;
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
        return sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

I also added [DataContract()] on the MainBaseClass and the child classes and the exception persists.

It only works if I do this, removing the [DataContract()] from the base class and the child classes previously. If not, I receive the results as an empty string "{}"

```
Class1 class1 = getData();
Package<Class1> package = new Package<Class1>();
package.AddObject(class1)
string str = new ServiceClass().Serialize<Package<Class>>(package);
```

Or this:

```
Class1 class1 = getData();
string str = new ServiceClass().Serialize<Class1>(class1);
```

So, how can I serialize multiple objects of different types?

Comment: Did you try [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)?

Comment: So, if I understand, this would be a limitation of the .net framework? Why is it not working at all? Meanwhile I will review your suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it. The only thing to do is to add DataContract attribute on the main base class only

```
[DataContract()]
public class MainBaseClass {}
```

Then, on each child class, we need to add the KnownType attribute

```
[KnownType(typeof(Class1))]
public class Class1 : MainBaseClass
{
}

[KnownType(typeof(Class2))]
public class Class2 : MainBaseClass
{
}
```

And that's it! That solved my initial problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you are going to use [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx), you need to decorate `MainBaseClass` with the [`KnownType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.knowntypeattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute to inform the serializer of all possible derived types *at compile time*.  This requirement is described in the documentation here: [Data Contract Known Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and here: [Stand-Alone JSON Serialization: Polymorphism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412170%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Class1))]
[KnownType(typeof(Class2))]
public abstract class MainBaseClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; } // For instance.
}

[DataContract]
public class Class1 : MainBaseClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public int attrib1 { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int attrib2 { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Class2 : MainBaseClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public int attribx { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int attriby { get; set; }
}
```

Having done so, an extra JSON property "__type" will be emitted for polymorphic fields of type `MainBaseClass` with value "DataContractName:DataContractNamespace".  This syntax is a .Net extension to the JSON standard and gives a hint which concrete type to use later when deserializing.  Thus if your `Package` class looks like:

```
[DataContract]
public class Package<T>
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<T> Objects = new List<T>();

    public Package() { }

    public void AddObject(T dto)
    {
        this.Objects.Add(dto);
    }
}
```

The JSON emitted will look like:

```
{"Objects":[{"__type":"Class1:#Tile.Question28612192","Id":101,"attrib1":1,"attrib2":2},{"__type":"Class2:#Tile.Question28612192","Id":-101,"attribx":-1,"attriby":-2}]}
```

If you don't want this, in .Net 4.5 and above, output of type information with `DataContractJsonSerializer` can be suppressed by setting [`DataContractJsonSerializerSettings.EmitTypeInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializersettings.emittypeinformation.aspx) to [`EmitTypeInformation.Never`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.emittypeinformation.aspx):

```
var settings = new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings { EmitTypeInformation = EmitTypeInformation.Never };
```

However, without the type information, you won't be able to deserialize your JSON with `DataContractJsonSerializer` later.

As an alternative, you could consider using Json.NET, which does not require advance knowledge of all possible derived types for serialization.  See here: [JSON serialization of array with polymorphic objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186973/json-serialization-of-array-with-polymorphic-objects) for details.